# Attach event to “v-btn” by pressing enter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Everything works except pressing the enter key need help.
I have форму ввода v-checkbox

```
   <v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel-header disable-icon-rotate @click="editingTarget" class="headerHeight">
        <span class="title"> {{description.targets}}</span>
        <template v-slot:actions>
            <v-btn fab small>
                <v-icon v-if="isEditing.target">mdi-close</v-icon>
                <v-icon v-else>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </template>
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <p class="subtitle-1  px-6" style="opacity: 0.9" v-if="(profileDetails) && (!isEditing.target)">
        {{profileDetails.target}}</p>
    <v-expansion-panel-content
    >
        <v-row>
            <v-col xs="12"
                   md="6"
                   lg="6"
                   v-for="(item, i) in valueCheckBox"
                   :key="i"
                   class="colCheckBox"
            >
                <div style="width: 250px">
                    <v-checkbox v-model="checkBox" :value="item.value">
                        <template v-slot:label>
                            <div class="check-box-custom">
                                <span class="font-weight-regular">{{item.value}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                    </v-checkbox>
                </div>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-card-actions>
            <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
                <v-btn
                        color="blue lighten-1"
                        @click="$emit('close-panel', []); save()"
                >
                    Save
                </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
   </v-expansion-panel>
```

I do not have "input", "form" if I entered any information on the form I would have succeeded but there is no form

```
        methods: {
        ...mapActions(['editAbout']),

        save() {
            this.isEditing.target = false

            const target = this.checkBox.join(", ")
            if (target !== profileDetails.target) {

                const obj = {
                    name: 'target',
                    profileDet: {
                        id: profileDetails.id,
                        target: target
                    }
                }
                this.editAbout(obj)
            }
        },
```

what just did not try ?! I think everything but somehow I can not
I just can't attach an event to the enter key
Helppp!!!

Comment: you have no keyboard handlers in your code . https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers

Comment: I know that they are not
They do not work! so I removed them and came here for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `@keydown.enter.native.stop.prevent="event"` prop in the corresponding tag (i.e. a `v-text-field`) to trigger `event()` upon releasing the enter key.

In your case, like this:

```
<v-checkbox @keydown.enter.native.stop.prevent="$emit('close-panel', []); save()" v-model="checkBox" :value="item.value">
```

Comment: please add an explanation of your answer.

Comment: Сorresponding tag (i.e. a v-text-field) work very well
but teg v-checkbox @keydown.enter ,@ key press, @ keyup etc doesn't work I don't know why